# How to view custom 404 page in Dropwizard

Tags: java, jetty, http-status-code-404, dropwizard, embedded-jetty

can anyone point me how to view my custom 404 page. I googled and tried implementing `ExceptionMapper<RuntimeException>` but this did not work fully. I'm using 0.8.1 version

My Exception mapper:

```
public class RuntimeExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<NotFoundException> {
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(NotFoundException exception) {
        Response defaultResponse = Response.status(Status.OK)
            .entity(JsonUtils.getErrorJson("default response"))
            .build();
        return defaultResponse;
    }
}
```

This only works on incorrect APIs and not on resource calls

My Setup :

```
@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<WebConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle("/webapp", "/", "index.html"));
}

@Override
public void run(WebConfiguration configuration, Environment environment) throws Exception {
    environment.jersey().register(RuntimeExceptionMapper.class);
    ((AbstractServerFactory) configuration.getServerFactory()).setJerseyRootPath("/api/*");

    // Registering Resources
    environment.jersey().register(new AuditResource(auditDao));
    ....
}
```

Now,

`http://localhost:8080/api/rubish` goes through overridden ExceptionMapper method
`http://localhost:8080/rubish.html` results in default 404 page

How do i setup so that whenever unknown pages are requested dropwizard will show up a custom 404 page

I refereed [this](http://gary-rowe.com/agilestack/2012/10/23/how-to-implement-a-runtimeexceptionmapper-for-dropwizard/) link for the exception mapper

Comment: is `/rubish.html` covered by the url-pattern mapping for your jersey layer? or is Jetty itself attempting to serve the content from that path?

Comment: Jetty is attempting to serve the content from that path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To configure a custom error page for any error, you can configure an ErrorPageErrorHandler in your Application like this:

```
@Override
public void run(final MonolithConfiguration config,
                final Environment env) {
    ErrorPageErrorHandler eph = new ErrorPageErrorHandler();
    eph.addErrorPage(404, "/error/404");
    env.getApplicationContext().setErrorHandler(eph);
}
```

Then create a resource like this:

```
@Path("/error")
public class ErrorResource {

    @GET
    @Path("404")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public Response error404() {
       return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND)
                      .entity("<html><body>Error 404 requesting resource.</body></html>")
                      .build();
    }
```

Just in case you need it, here's the import for ErrorPageErrorHandler as well:

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ErrorPageErrorHandler;
```

Comment: Instead of returning HTML string i used, `Response.seeOther(new URI("/index.html")).build();` Thanks :)

Comment: Your comment reminds me that I had a further problem with this.  The code above will indeed return the html provided, but the response status will be 200, not 404!  I'll update with the correct code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand it right, what you want is to serve a custom 404 page for unmatched resource requests. To do this you could write a separate resource class and in it a separate resource method. This resource method should have an

> @Path("/{default: .*}")

annotation. This resource method catches unmatched resource requests. In this method you can serve your own custom view.

Look at the below code snippet for clarity,

```
@Path("/")
public class DefaultResource {

  /**
   * Default resource method which catches unmatched resource requests. A page not found view is
   * returned.
   */
  @Path("/{default: .*}")
  @GET
  public View defaultMethod() throws URISyntaxException {
    // Return a page not found view.
    ViewService viewService = new ViewService();
    View pageNotFoundView = viewService.getPageNotFoundView();
    return pageNotFoundView;
  }

}
```

You can refer to [this](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/11/serving-static-assets-with-dropwizard/) if you are unaware of how to serve static assets using dropwizard or ask me.

Comment: Using the `defaultResource` im able catch `http://localhost:8080/api/rubish`... I want to catch `http://localhost:8080/rubish.html`.. which is a html page request

Comment: Do you have a resource (or resource method) with a url pattern rubish.html ??  If there is already a registered resource with this url pattern rubish.html, default resource (mentioned in my answer) will not be able to catch that request. Only those requests which are uncaught by any other resource will be caught by default resource.

Comment: All resources are prepended with `api`... rublish.html is a request for a static html page. it is not registered under resources